# Transit Visa for a Ukrainian at Oman Airport

Tags: air-travel, airport-transfer, ukrainian-citizens, oman, muscat

I want to book a flight for my wife from the UK to Manila with a change at Muscat Airport.

We have no intention of leaving the airport.

Will she need a visa?

Comment: I've added the "Ukrainian-citizens" tag to the question, but if your wife (or anyone else traveling with her) are not traveling on a Ukranian passport, you should edit the question to indicate this clearly.

Answer (score 1):

- If your transit time is less than 6 hours, you don't need a transit visa.
- If your transit time is between 6 and 72 hours, you need a visa, and can get it on arrival.

A [Timatic search using the Emirates site](https://www.emirates.com/hk/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=UA&NV=Ukraine&DC=PH&DV=Philippines&TC=OM&TV=Oman&h=46722deb468cce7f6f8dc2747bd5f110da4fe8dd) says:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 6 hours.
>
> Visa Issuance:
>   Passengers in transit for longer than 6 hours can obtain a single transit visa 
>   on arrival for a maximum stay of 72 hours. They must have a have confirmation 
>   from the airline that a visa has been approved before departure.